# Selecting element from xml using xmlquery in Db2 (SQL/XML)

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, db2, xquery

I have created table in Db2 like this:

```
create table xml_file(data xml not null)
```

This is the exact structure of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <student id="20140021">
          <name>Tom</name>
          <surname>Johnson</surname>
          <birth_date>"05/11/1995"</birth_date>
          <birth_place>"Miami"</birth_place>
          <points>9.45</points>
     </student>
```

I want to select id, name, surname, and points for all students whose names are Ben and birth places are Chicago.

I wrote something like this:

```
select xmlquery('$DATA/student/data(@id)') as ID,
       xmlquery('$DATA/student/name/text()') as NAME,
       xmlquery('$DATA/student/surname/text()') as SURNAME,
       xmlquery('$DATA/student/points/text()') as POINTS
from xml_file
where xmlexists('$DATA/student[birth_place = "Chicago"]')
and xmlexists('$DATA/student[name = "Ben"]');
```

All I got is this message: **"FETCHED 0 RECORDS, 0 RECORDS SHOWN"** (this is in IBM Data Studio).

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH xml_file (data) AS 
(
VALUES
XMLPARSE
(DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <student id="20140021">
          <name>Tom</name>
          <surname>Johnson</surname>
          <birth_date>"05/11/1995"</birth_date>
          <birth_place>"Miami"</birth_place>
          <points>9.45</points>
     </student>'
)
)
*/
SELECT X.*
FROM 
  xml_file V
, XMLTABLE
  ('$doc/student' PASSING V.data AS "doc"
   COLUMNS
     ID      INT         PATH '@id'
   , NAME    VARCHAR(20) PATH 'name'
   , SURNAME VARCHAR(20) PATH 'surname'
   , POINTS  DEC(5, 2)   PATH 'points'
  ) X
WHERE XMLEXISTS('$doc/student[birth_place = """Miami""" and name = "Tom"]' PASSING V.data AS "doc");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your two `where xmlexists`s with one (this is used with your sample xml in the question, not your code):

```
where xmlexists('$DATA//student[birth_place/text()['Miami']][name/text()["Tom"]]');
```

or, two are required:

```
where xmlexists('$DATA/student[birth_place/text()['Miami']]')
and xmlexists('$DATA/student[name/text()["Tom"]]');
```

and see if either works.

Comment: It didn't work. There is a problem with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

The birth-place element contains double quotations marks which lead to an XPath evaluation error. To avoid this, replace `where xmlexists('$DATA/student[birth_place = "Chicago"]')` with one the following XPath expression :

XPath 1.0 friendly :

```
where xmlexists('$DATA/student/birth_place[substring(.,2,string-length(/student/birth_place)-2)="Chicago"]')
```

XPath 2.0 friendly :

```
where xmlexists('$DATA/student/birth_place[translate(.,codepoints-to-string(34),"")="Chicago"]')
```

XPath used to test on your sample data :

```
/student/birth_place[substring(.,2,string-length(/student/birth_place)-2)="Miami"]
/student/birth_place[translate(.,codepoints-to-string(34),"")="Miami"]
```

Comment: Can you explain me what . and 2 in substring(., 2, string-length(/student/birth_place)-2) means?

Comment: Sure. `.` means the current node and `2` is the "character position in string at which the part to be taken begins". So you have : substring(content of the current node, start position, length of your desired output).